# WIndows automatically connects to my BLE device

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a BLE device I am trying to write an application to communicate with.
I am facing a really annoying issue - windows automatically connects to my BLE device.
This is a very big issue for me, because when windows automatically connects, my application has no way of accessing this device(the moment I try to `WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify)`

I get some weird undocumented exception:

`WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync Exception: Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))`

Is there any way I can disable this auto-connect thing, either on the windows, or by my ble device(maybe some bluetooth protocol hack, I have a friend whos doing the BLE device firmware)?

Is there any way my application to use the already established connection by windows(I can't make it work so far)?

Is it possible my application to kill the auto windows connection and establish a new one, my application connection(I couldn't make that work either)?

By now I am really out of ideas and I have no clue how to make this work.

Comment: Can't you just unpair the devices?

Comment: I tried that before - I unpair the device, afterwards I initiate a connection myself, but winows pops up the numeric comparison window to pair the devices. 
When that happens I accept the pair and I get into the above situation.

Comment: But now I did not accept the windows pair procedure and somehow it opened connection to the device. This is very strange since it should have some authentication/security levels, because it clearly pops up the numeric comparison pop up.

Comment: Have you tried to call the `DeviceInformationPairing.UnpairAsync` method in your app, after you've paired the BLE device？Then will the system pair the device automatically?

Answer (score 0):

[Untested]
I don't have the same problem as you so the below solution is untested but something to try.

You can programatically ask windows to hold on to a connection and to automatically reconnect if the device comes in range:

```
GattSession.FromDeviceIdAsync(mBleDevice.BluetoothDeviceId);
session.MaintainConnection = true;
```

Perhaps setting that to false will ensure that Windows doesn't automatically reconnect.

This is strange though because if Windows is paired you should be able to still connect and use the device in code. So I suspect something else is going on.